# In virtualbox, I can't access the dvd drive to install a guest host

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 12.04 and VirtualBox 4.3.  I have set up a VM called "MediaServer" and tried to start it.  I then get the following error:

```
Cannot open host device '/dev/sr0' for readonly access.
Check the permissions of that device ('/bin/ls -l /dev/sr0'):
Most probably you need to be member of the device group.
Make sure that you logout/login after changing the group settings of the current user (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

I have looked all over the Internet and have been unable to find a solution.  Using Webmin, I tried changing the group settings so that my user name was in the `vboxusers` group, but that did not work either.  I tried various other changes in group settings and none of them worked.

Also, I tried rebooting the server after the changes and that didn't work either.

I have been following a guide on how to set up an Ubuntu server from the website "linuxhomeserverguide.com" and when it came to the section where you could finally set up your first virtual machine, I am stumped.  I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Is your user in the group `cdrom`?

Answer (score 1):

Your user must be in the `cdrom` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G cdrom $USER
```

Restart the system and try again.